# "command not found" after editing /etc/profile

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/) to add a JAVA variable for all users. I then opened the editor that my hosting service supplies and added the last 2 lines. **Centos 5.9** server.

```
# /etc/profile
    
# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup
# Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc

pathmunge () {
    if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
       if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
          PATH=$PATH:$1
       else
          PATH=$1:$PATH
       fi
    fi
}

# ksh workaround
if [ -z "$EUID" -a -x /usr/bin/id ]; then 
    EUID=`id -u`
    UID=`id -ru`
fi

# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /sbin
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
fi

# No core files by default
ulimit -S -c 0 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ -x /usr/bin/id ]; then
    USER="`id -un`"
    LOGNAME=$USER
    MAIL="/var/spool/mail/$USER"
fi

HOSTNAME=`/bin/hostname`
HISTSIZE=1000

if [ -z "$INPUTRC" -a ! -f "$HOME/.inputrc" ]; then
    INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
fi

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC

# By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for login shell
# Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
# You could check uidgid reservation validity in
# /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
if [ $UID -gt 99 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
    umask 002
else
    umask 022
fi

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . $i
        else
            . $i >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    fi
done

unset i
unset pathmunge
#cPanel Added local::lib -- BEGIN
LOCALLIBUSER=$USER
if [ -e "/usr/bin/whoami" ]; then
        LOCALLIBUSER=`/usr/bin/whoami`
fi
if [ "$LOCALLIBUSER" != "root" ]; then
    eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)
fi
#cPanel Added local::lib -- END

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_41/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_41/bin
```

After I relog in I get:

[image]

The problem is that I need to configure the Java home variable. **I am still getting that error even if I delete what I added on the last two lines**. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to strip your init file down to the parts that actually cause the error?

Comment: "the editor that my hosting service supplies" - what is that? Any chance it could have messed with the line endings?

Comment: Im not sure what editor is it, but its just a text editor. Then I typed in the last two lines that the tuturial stated.

Comment: Well, for one, you don't need that line *twice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much like the editor you used changed newline (‘\n’) characters (which are numerically equal to line-feed (LF) characters) with CR+LF sequences (CR = carriage return).  In their totality, the error messages you showed don’t make a lot of sense, but this portion jumped out at me:

> `` …bash: /etc/profile: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `{ ``
>   **`'`**

That’s saying that the “unexpected token” is a `{` followed by a CR.